# Send umat or image in memory to web client and display in html

Tags: asp.net, .net, typescript, aurelia, emgucv

I have a aurelia client that gets a image from my asp.net server via my API. The image is stored as a png file and is loaded when the api call is done.

This works fine but the image is from a webcam that gets images via Emgu cv.

My question is if it is possible to directly serve the current Umat/Mat image and display it on the webpage.

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        try
        {

         Console.WriteLine("Get image 3");
        manager.sem.WaitOne();

        // Maybe firsto to Emgu cv Umat to .net Image (bitmap?)
        // Then image to byte.memory stream
        // Send

        Image<Bgr, Byte> myImage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(ddEngine.ResultImage.Bitmap);

        response.Content =
            new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(opencvCam.ResultImage.Bytes));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");


        manager.sem.Release();
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ex");
    }
```

My client code looks like this:

```
  updateImageSrc() {
    let dt = new Date();
    let baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/status/dummymethod3";
    this.imagePath = baseUrl + "?t=" + dt.getTime();
}
```

And the html

```
    <img id="img" src.bind="imagePath"/>
```

The page does not display any image.

Comment: Did you verify that your server side code works? If not, first hard code the URL in the markup: *<img id="Img" src=http://localhost:8080/api/status/dummymethod3?t=random"/>*

Comment: Thanks for the comment ill will try this in a hours. I think that the problem is also indeed in the server. The convertion between umat/mat to a image and it's sending. The problem is that the current solution is that i convert and store the umat image to png and then read it out again. But i don't want to save it on disk. On the server i want it to keep on the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you already have a work around using

```
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

I don't think that converting to an array is the most efficient way (you should see some performance degradation with larger images)

My recomendation use the StreamContent. Your code needs to change a bit:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[System.Web.Http.Route("dummymethod3")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get2()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Get image 3");
        ddEngine.sem.WaitOne();

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        ResultImage.Bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");

        ddEngine.sem.Release();

        return result;
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ex");
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for you're comment i will check this tommorow!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, first get cget the bitmap from the Umat/mat. Then make a memory stream. Save the image to the created memorystream in the image format you want (png in this case). Next use the stream to create a byte array and put the created byte array in the content property of the HTTPResponseMessage. Also set the content type to the image type, in my case png.

This way there is no actual image written to disk and it is kept on the heap of the server application.

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("dummymethod3")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get2()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Get image 3");
            ddEngine.sem.WaitOne();
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            image = ResultImage.Bitmap;
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");

            ddEngine.sem.Release();

            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ex");
        }

        return response;
    }
```